# What font ubuntu uses

Tags: fonts

I was wondering what is the default for Linux Ubuntu, I really like it, could any one let me know what font it is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its simply called Ubuntu font. http://font.ubuntu.com
It is also the font used on Ask Ubuntu:

```
font-family: Ubuntu, Arial, "libra sans", sans-serif;
```

Here's a sample image of how Ubuntu Font looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, very nice font, going to use a similar for a Java program am doing.

Comment: @user242294. It's available under free licensing. Depending on which license you use, it should be possible to use the Ubuntu font itself, not just a similar one.

Answer (score 1):

Its called Ubuntu, made by Ubuntu.

See http://font.ubuntu.com/ for more info.